# I need to comprehend the definition of deliberately bringing kufr thoughts to mind. All the cases. Please may Allah reward you

Tags: halal-haram, fiqh, sin, image, kufr

I have been reading an enciclopedia of things about Islam in the past ten years, so please don't treat me as a beginner.  We all agree that deliberately bringing blasphemous and kufr thoughts to mind, puts you beyond the pale of islam. But the term deliberate is wide and vague. We all agree that if I bring to mind the sentence  with the intention of believing it, that puts you beyond the pale of Islam. But I can bring that sentence to mind even without believing it,  even without approving it, even without liking it. For example: I am staying idle and for no reason I (not waswas) imagine the voice of a priest that says  or I imagine the verse of the Bible that says < The almighty has children> because I remember how that verse looked like when I read it in the Bible 5 years ago out of curiosity. I visually imagine it as a sentence word by word. My question is: Are the two cases described in the last part of the questions considered or called < Deliberately bringing blasphemous and kufr thoughts to mind>  The case of imagining the voice of a priest and the case of visually imagining a sentence from the Bible word by word. To be honest with you, in seventy per cent of cases, either I haven't received an answer at all or the answer hasn't fulfilled my needs. I invite contributers like Muslimah , Medi1 Saif and others without excluding anybody to at least give their personal opinion.

Comment: I don't get what you are talking about: I wonder what you think is  blasphemous in the given "example". Have in mind that some people want to read this so use some layout to make your text readable etc. Beside this login in with different guest accounts isn't helpful if you want a question answered as you'll need to react to the comments in order to get answers.

Answer (score 1):

Relevant verse from which we can draw an analogy:

> وقد نزل عليكم في الكتاب أن إذا سمعتم آيات الله يكفر بها ويستهزأ بها فلا تقعدوا معهم حتى يخوضوا في حديث غيره إنكم إذا مثلهم إن الله جامع المنافقين والكافرين في جهنم جميعا  (And it has already come down to you in the Book that when you hear the verses of Allah [recited], they are denied [by them] and ridiculed; so do not sit with them until they enter into another conversation. Indeed, **you would then be like them**. Indeed Allah will gather the hypocrites and disbelievers in Hell all together) - Qur'an 4:140

We see that Allah (ﷻ) condemned those who stayed in the presence of disbelievers when they were mocking Islam and said that if they were to remain in the presence of such Kufr, they are "like them" i.e., if they AGREE then they are also disbelievers and if they DISAGREE but remain there then they are getting an equivalent level of sin to them. No IFs, ANDs or BUTs about it.

This is a similar situation @:

> I can bring that sentence to mind even without believing it, even without approving it, even without liking it.

It's haram for you to do so. It's not Kufr but you're still getting sin for it. And not only that but calling such thoughts to mind also risks your faith, all the more reason making it forbidden.

I hope this helps settle the matter in your mind, inshaAllah.

> To be honest with you, in seventy per cent of cases, either I haven't received an answer at all or the answer hasn't fulfilled my needs

Sadly, your questions about thoughts/waswasa are repetitive and slight variations of each other. You could very well come up with millions of different scenarios/cases and ask about each of them as a "new question".. but these have in reality already been answered sufficiently.